# Preventing users from using global search in SF Classic UI

Tags: javascript, console, global-search, salesforce-classic

I have to ban certain profiles from using global search in service console. For this purpose, I created a hidden console component that hosts a VF that utilizes several Console Toolkit methods. It immediately closes the tabs that open upon submitting a search in global search box (by checking opened tab's link).

However, users still can skip this enforcement by clicking "my settings" or "my profile", switching to SF Classic UI and using global search there. Is there anything I can fix this exploit? I have thought of:

1. Removing / preventing such links that switches the UI to SF Classic
2. Inserting script to SF Classic pages.
3. Preventing redirect out from service console.

So far, my impression is that all of them are not possible to apply. Is there any other workarounds I may be abble to apply?

Comment: Why would you want to disable the global search? A bit of an X-Y problem maybe?

Comment: I can't answer this since the client requested so and we haven't questioned this query yet. However, I guess applying a detailed reconfguration in sharing settings & permission sets instead of tinkering with global search will yield a better result here.